# Getting divide by zero error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have having a divide by zero error. Please help me in this.

```
    ,CASE U.BasePool 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A'
        WHEN -1 THEN 'N/A'
        ELSE CASE 
                WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) > U.BasePool THEN 'IN-OVERAGE'
                --WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) + (SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum) > U.BasePool THEN DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE())
                ELSE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(MM,CAST(ROUND((U.BasePool - SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)) 
                            /(SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum),0) as INT), GETDATE()),101)

                --(basepool - sumcontract) / (sumcontract/monthNum ) is the expected months to reach overage
            END 

        END AS  ExpectedDate
```

Comment: you can not divide by 0 please handle this error in catch.

Comment: I have never used catch. can you help me in this

Comment: Well, the problem is that you're diving by zero. Unless you show us the complete query, table structures and table data, we probably can't help you.

Comment: Do a test to see if the denominator is 0. If it is, do something else.

Comment: I posted answer please refer syntax and try it

Answer (score 1):

In the case, first check if `(SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum),0) as INT)` = `0`. If so, return a specific value you desire (like `NULL`).

Comment: use `Nullif(Expression,0)` instead of checking with `0`.BTW why `Sum(sum(B.TransactionCount)) `? It should be replaced with `sum(B.TransactionCount)`

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the motivation behind that, and just copied the exact piece from the question.

Comment: I used a case for this but now I am facing one more problem. showing message : Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

Comment: @user1677027 Sounds like a different problem. Please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Try & Catch in SQL Server: References taken from MSDN
Syntax is as below .

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT *
        FROM sys.messages
        WHERE message_id = 21;
END TRY
GO
-- The previous GO breaks the script into two batches,
-- generating syntax errors. The script runs if this GO
-- is removed.
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
END CATCH;
GO
```

With in Begin Try block you can write your statements and if any error occur in that statements then it will handle by Catch block.

Comment: I don't think this will be helpful to OP. OP already knows an error occurs in the query and is trying to fix it, not report on it.

Comment: please read my above comments he wants to know how to handle error so here i just explane that part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CASE with ISNULL(../NULLIF()) check expression

```
,CASE U.BasePool 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'N/A'
    WHEN -1 THEN 'N/A'
    ELSE CASE 
            WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) > U.BasePool THEN 'IN-OVERAGE'
            --WHEN SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount)) OVER (Partition by U.ContractID) + (SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum) > U.BasePool THEN DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE())
            ELSE  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(MM,CAST(ROUND((U.BasePool - SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)) 
                        /NULLIF((SUM(SUM(B.TransactionCount))  OVER (Partition by U.ContractID)/MonthNum), 0), 0) as INT), GETDATE()) ,101), 0)
            --(basepool - sumcontract) / (sumcontract/monthNum ) is the expected months to reach overage
        END 
    END AS  ExpectedDate
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12837)